# How to generate sign to pass to transferPreSigned(), contract is not asking for sign while transfer()

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, metamask, erc20

I'm creating ERC865 token so that users can send tokens without having ether. I followed [1](https://hackernoon.com/you-dont-need-ether-to-transfer-tokens-f3ae373606e1) and [2](https://medium.com/coinmonks/transfer-ethereum-tokens-without-ether-an-erc20-improvement-to-seriously-consider-90bebd447bb).

As per 1, sender will sign transaction object while calling transfer() but I'm unable to see any "Sign"! What parameters should be passed to transferPreSigned()? I'm using Metamask and Solidity.